# Open source Distributed computing tool

Tags: distributed-computing

I want to set up distributed computing on my Local Area Network consisting a bunch of PCs. Say for the time being each one has the same OS -  Windows 7.

Is there any opensource tool available so that I can share the resources of these PCs over the LAN and increase the speed of my applications and the memory space. I know that if its a graphics intensive application then, it is not very practical, because the speed of LAN is much slower than Graphics processors. But I only want to share general applications, some basic softwares, Programming language IDEs etc.

Can anyone shed some light on it? 
Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without spending money on specialized hardware and software, I would look into building a linux-based [Beowulf cluster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beowulf_cluster). The Wikipedia article lists some FOSS software that can be used to achieve this:

- [Parallel Virtual Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PVM)
- Message Passing Interface:

  - [OpenMPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMPI)
  - [MPICH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPICH) (available for OS X as well as Windows)

Comment: Beowulf sounds gr8...so here I can attach a node running windows into the system? I need to run mainly windows application... Because primarily Beowulf is based on unix like OS, but using PVM and MPICH can I achieve parallel computing.....
So PVM will divide my tasks into several fragments and send it to the group of computers and collect the result after computation is done..But I need to install the those PVMs into those windows nodes also

am i right?

Comment: @Prasenjit: It's not that simple. PVM and MPICH come with tools that allow you to parallelize existing programs if you have the source code. But you can't just install PVM/MPICH on a bunch of computers and expect Visual Studio to run faster. The software has to be compiled to take advantage of the PVM virtual machine or MPICH's message passing library.

Comment: Thanks very much for the clarification...so parallel processing is achieved from source code level, I was thinking, that these PVM stuffs will take the charge of process and thread scheduling from binary level and distribute across the attached nodes.

Comment: @Prasenjit: Nah, it's not that simple unfortunately. Just like programs have to be specifically written to be multithreaded to take advantage of multiprocessing, or written for a 64-bit OS to take advantage of a 64-bit CPU architecture, a piece of software also has to be written using MPI or PVM's API to take advantage of these parallel computing platforms.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't reccomend windows 7 at all, you would need to switch to windows azure which is cloud based or windows server..

Heres what i would reccomend that would stay within open soruce

It's a big process to setup a cluster..proper network configuration I.E. infiniband or ethernet
you need to install a linux server..Redhat , ubuntu ,gentoo , debian exc...
setup resource and job management tools